why is the "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined" problem so hard to diagnose in my nextjs app?
I am using Nextjs, and want to call process.env from within a page. I overrode the default Document with _document.js and wrote this:
export default function Document() {
 return (
  <Html>
   <Head>
    <Script>{`console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV)`}</Script>
   </Head>
  </Html>

This causes a "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined" error in console. My ultimate intent is to load a GA4 script in production environment and not development. I know how to do that part, but where I am confused is why process is undefined. It works outside the function, but not inside it.
Why?

You should reword your question to bette explain what are you want to achieve and where the error that you mention in the title is coming from.

I've edited it. Is it more clear?

@keinsell can you please elaborate on how the question is unclear? to me it very clearly says that im trying to conditionally load some scripts based on environment, and that the answers offered elsewhere on the internet (numbered 1-4 in my list) are insufficient

Where does this _document.js script run? Is it in a web browser? The client (the web browser) is a completely different runtime than the server/bundler, the former doesn't have access to whatever properties you set in the latter unless you inject them. You need to have some mechanism for replacing all occurrences of process.env...  in your code with the actual value when it's bundled/served to the client. Not sure how that's done next.js but it's commonly handled with a plugin.

@Lennholm thank you! with nextjs, appending "NEXT_PUBLIC_" to your env vars is supposed to inject them into the server build. my issue (as stated in the title) is that "process" is undefined.

also @Lennholm _document.js runs in the server

This is happening because process object is not available inside an inline script. It is only accessible to the function and not html elements and/or browser. instead, create a variable in the function as -
export default function Document() {
const publicEnv= process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV;
return (
  <Html>
   <Head>
    <Script>{`console.log(publicEnv)}</Script>
   </Head>
  </Html>
  )
}

